# How to set a maximum height to Label Xamarin Forms?

Tags: string, label, height, max, xamarin.forms

I need your help !

In xamarin.forms, I would like a Label with a fixed Width. When the text is too long, it is on several lines. So, I would like set a maximum height or number of lines. 
I think to measure the string lengh but I no found method.

I hope there is a solution to Xamarin.Forms (PCL project). I don't want to do specific code for each platform if it's possible.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution.

When I set HeightRequest property to Label, it didn't work.
When I wrapped the Label in a StackLayout and set HeightRequest property to the StackLayout, I succeeded.

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="70">
    <Label Text="..." />
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use "MaxLines" to display how many lines you want.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options available. If you don't want the label to wrap you can set the `Label.LineBreakMode` to `NoWrap`. More info [here.](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.LineBreakMode/)

You can directly [specify](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.HeightRequest/) a `HeightRequest` or set `VerticalOptions` [on the Label.](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.View.VerticalOptions/)

Try posting a code example of what you have tried for more assistance.